# Setup multiple Cloud SQL connections on Google App Engine (Laravel 6.2)

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up multiple MySQL connections on my Laravel 6.2 web app deployed with Google App Engine.

Everything worked when I had a single MySQL databse (stored on Cloud SQL) but I can't get the hand on any documentation to set up multiple connections in my app.yaml file.

All the connections you can see in the screenshot of the config/database.php work properly in a local environment.

*App.yaml:*

[image: App.yaml file]
*config/database.php:*

[image: config/datbase.php file]

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: I was reading your app.yaml and I can see that you are using an example from somewhere to set the app.yaml, could you share this example? Additionally, are you using App Engine flex or standard, or are there any considerations for your Cloud SQL instances such as VPC networks?

Comment: Hello, I was following this tutorial : https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-web-app-on-google-app-engine-ecfbb0d49b00.

I am using a flex environment and I don't use VPC networks.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for App Engine. Instead I switched to Compute Engine and everything works fine because I don't have to create a app.yaml file or to change anything from my local environment. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: I have done some tests, but you would need to set up a lot of thing is order to achieve this and would not be in the best practices to do so. As you mention the best thing would be to try this through Compute Engine if you really need to reach multiple Cloud SQL instances.